# Create table of every unique comdination from several lists

Tags: excel, vba

I have fours lists in Excel of arbitraty lenght.

```
A    B    C    D
A1   B1   C1   D1
A2   B2   C2   D2
A3   B3        D3
A4             D4
               D5
```

I want to create one table that has every combination from the lists as rows.

```
A    B    C    D
A1   B1   C1   D1
A1   B1   C1   D2
...
A4   B3   C2   D5
```

Is there any simple way to do this in Excel - using Excel functionality, formulas or VBA?

Comment: To clarify - are there any duplicates in the initial lists? Or would each value be unique within its own column?

Comment: No, there are no duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some nested for statements should handle this problem. Just put this in the VBA for your project and it will create a macro called CreateTable() which should put the table in a new worksheet for you.

```
Sub CreateTable()
'Creates a table will all combinations of values from four columns

Dim a, b, c, d As Range

'Activates sheet that has data on it to be copied to table
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate 'Change Sheet1 to the name of your sheet


'Change A2 to first cell of data you want to be copied over
Set a = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set b = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
Set c = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))
Set d = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))
Dim i As Integer
i = 1 'Row number of the first row of data for the table of combinations

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate 'Change Sheet2 to name of sheet you want the     table to be put on

For Each cellA In a.Cells
    For Each cellB In b.Cells
       For Each cellC In c.Cells
            For Each cellD In d.Cells
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1) = cellA.Value
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2) = cellB.Value
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3) = cellC.Value
                Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4) = cellD.Value
                i = i + 1
            Next cellD
        Next cellC
    Next cellB
Next cellA

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, shortly beaten. I agree your method is simpler, to use the cellcount of each given range to determine the length of each loop, rather than setting an additional set of variables. However consider that using xldown to find the last row can cause errors (where there is only a single row, or where there are breaks in data). Though in this case it seems not to matter.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your four lists next to each other, highlight the data and insert a pivot table.

Add each of the columns to the "rows" section of the pivot table.
Right-click on each field in turn and click on "Field Settings".
Set the Layout and print to show tabular form, repeated item labels and items with no data as follows.

[image]

And this is the resulting table.

[image]

I suspect you'll want to delete the rows which contain 1 or more (blank) rows.
This is probably easiest by adding a formula to column E along the lines of

```
=IF(A2="(blank)",1,0)
```

Repeat this for the other columns, Add them up and sort by the total.
Delete all rows that have a non-zero entry.

Comment: Great solution, thank you! Both work well for me. This solution is the one I will actually end up using as I prefer not to need VBA in this case.

Comment: If you prefer not to use VBA, then you should say that in your question. Vague questions without an attempt to answer are pretty frustrating to see.

Answer (score 0):

You should show what you've tried already and give specifics of where your data is coming from, but here's a VBA solution. Loops through each item in a given column, for as many rows as there are total combinations of items.

```
Sub Combination_Table()

Dim rList1 As Range
Dim rList2 As Range
Dim rList3 As Range
Dim rList4 As Range

Dim lLength1 As Long
Dim lLength2 As Long
Dim lLength3 As Long
Dim lLength4 As Long

Dim lRowcounter As Long
Sheets(1).Activate
With Sheets(1)
    lLength1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    lLength2 = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    lLength3 = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    lLength4 = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1

    Set rList1 = .Range("A2:A" & lLength1)
    Set rList2 = .Range("B2:B" & lLength2)
    Set rList3 = .Range("C2:C" & lLength3)
    Set rList4 = .Range("D2:D" & lLength4)

End With

'The above marks the ranges containing the original un-combined lists,
'with no duplicates and assuming row 1 is the header and all data is on
'columns A-D, without blanks.

rowcounter = 0
Sheets(2).Activate

For i = 1 To lLength1
    For j = 1 To lLength2
        For k = 1 To lLength3
            For l = 1 To lLength4
                rowcounter = rowcounter + 1

                Sheets(2).Range("A" & rowcounter).Formula = rList1(i, 1).Text
                Sheets(2).Range("B" & rowcounter).Formula = rList2(j, 1).Text
                Sheets(2).Range("C" & rowcounter).Formula = rList3(k, 1).Text
                Sheets(2).Range("D" & rowcounter).Formula = rList4(l, 1).Text
'This changes the text in columns A-D for the given rowcount, to the current
'iteration of the current looped value from the above lists
            Next l
        Next k
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This Works too and this is simpler.

```
    Sub t()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long, lastcol As Long
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

      LastRow = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
      lastcol = sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count

        k = 0

        For i = 2 To LastRow
        j = 1
        k = k + 1
            For j = 1 To lastcol
            sht.Cells(i, j).Value = sht.Cells(1, j) & k
            Next
    Next
    End Sub
```